# How to open url using SpriteKit and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

How do you open a URL in Xcode using SpriteKit with Swift when a sprite node is pressed. I want it to open in Safari rather than inside the app. I have this so far:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.WebButton{
}
```

Comment: You can open an URL Like this-UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"http://www.apple.com"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way you can open link in Safari:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

    if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.WebButton{
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com"))  //you can add your link here
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help you..:)